# "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" Springboot 3.2.1 gateway + Springsecurity 6.2.1

Tags: spring, security, token, csrf

I am working on a basic microservices architecture system. Currently, I am trying to implement security on my gateway. However, when I try to send a POST via Postman to http://localhost:8765/api/auth/register, I keep getting "An expected CSRF token cannot be found"

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hYKA.png)

This is my securityFilterChain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(httpBasic -> {});

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the log that Springboot throws when receiving the POST (note that this doesn't mention anything about CSRF)

```
2024-03-16 17:46:05 [http-nio-8765-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer - Received [POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.37.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: e11ef3a5-dad1-46e6-94b9-b2c436ed236d
Host: localhost:8765
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61

{
    "username": "tobias",
    "password": "password"
}]
2024-03-16 17:46:05 [http-nio-8765-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Any hints or ideas? There are a few questions similar to this one in Stackoverflow, but non has been resolved yet.

[This is the project](https://github.com/tobiolea97/glosary-api/tree/master/api-gateway/src/main/java/com/mule/daily/practice/apigateway) on Github for you to check.

I tried different alternatives and configuration on securityFilterChain, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful for someone, the problem was that I was using @EnableWebSecurity, which enables security for a servlet-type web app.

Given that I am working on a gateway (and therefore on a Reactive app), @EnableWebFluxSecurity should be used. Keep in mind that other things must also be adjusted.